# Dotnet Core Web API returning empty list | Lazy loading do not work

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an endpoint in my API which returns all the data of a selected item. The item is a root object called `Survey` and it has a list of pages.

```
public partial class Surveys
{
    public Surveys()
    {
        Pages = new HashSet<Pages>();
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Syear { get; set; }
    public long Quarter { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pages> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

Model class for the `Pages` look like this.

```
public partial class Pages
{
    public Pages()
    {
        Elements = new HashSet<Elements>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? PageFlowId { get; set; }
    public bool NamedPage { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFirst { get; set; }
    public bool? IsLast { get; set; }
    public long? SurveyQuarter { get; set; }
    public long? SurveySyear { get; set; }

    public PagesFlows PageFlow { get; set; }
    public Surveys Survey { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Elements> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

But when I send the GET request is returning an empty list for `Pages`

```
[
    {
        "description": "Customer Satisfaction Survey",
        "name": "Customer Survey",
        "syear": 2019,
        "quarter": 1,
        "pages": []
    }
]
```

The database contains data. primary key of the table is a composite key(Syear, Quarter). My API looks like this.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSurveys([FromRoute]long syear, long quarter)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var surveys = await _context.Surveys.Include(s => s.Pages).SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Syear == syear && s.Quarter == quarter);
        if (surveys == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(surveys);
    }
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a week now.  Any help will be highly appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any other approaches? Like getting the survey and then selecting the pages based on the id of the selected survey? In your EF, I am not seeing how you relate the two entities to each other.

Comment: Problem is my parameters are not getting parsed on to the GetSurveys method. I am relating two entities by [public ICollection<Pages> Pages { get; set; }] on Surveys model and [public Surveys Survey { get; set; }] in Pages model. Is that not enough?

Comment: If `Pages` is empty, then there are no pages related to the survey that matches the `syear` and `quarter` you've specified. Simple as that. Check your database, the data there is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Chris I checked the database and there i can see the data exists. Actually  I added those data via this API using the POST method, data retrieval is the problem it seems.

Comment: Not trying to be difficult, but this isn't exactly rocket science, and it's virtually impossible that you've stumbled upon a bug in EF Core in something as fundamental and simplistic as a select with a join, especially since millions of developers are using this in production without issue. Either it's not using the database you think it's using, or the data you think is correct, is in fact not, but this is a data issue on your end.

Comment: @Chris Exactly, I have done this before a million times. That is why I dont understand what is going on. I'd better look at the environment and see what is wrong as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get around the issue by doing the following.
Removed `.Include(s => s.Pages)` from here,

```
var surveys = await _context.Surveys.Include(s => s.Pages).SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Syear == syear && s.Quarter == quarter);
```

I have added `virtual` keyword to all the referenced classes.

```
public partial class Pages
{
    public Pages()
    {
        Elements = new HashSet<Elements>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? PageFlowId { get; set; }
    public bool NamedPage { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFirst { get; set; }
    public bool? IsLast { get; set; }
    public long? SurveyQuarter { get; set; }
    public long? SurveySyear { get; set; }

    public virtual PagesFlows PageFlow { get; set; }
    public virtual Surveys Survey { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Elements> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` package fron NuGet as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading)

And enabled Lazy Loading Proxies in `Sturtup.cs` in `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>
                (options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(connection));
```